# Join on "2 columns" is extremely slow

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables, which I need to `INNER JOIN on 2 equal columns` like this:

```
SELECT
    `table1`.*
FROM
    `table1`
    INNER JOIN `table2`
        ON  `table2`.`type` = `table1`.`type`
        AND `table2`.`num`  = `table1`.`num`
WHERE
    `table2`.`another_int` = 1
ORDER BY
    `table1`.`id` DESC
LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0
```

When I try it, the query takes **`1500ms`**

But removing any of the 2 JOIN conditions, or removing the `ORDER BY` will cause the query to run in **`1ms`**

---

More info:

- Table 2 has 1500 rows and Table 1 has ~400,000 rows
- Both type and num columns are indexed on both tables and the `id`
  (sort by) on table 1 is also primary, so indexed.
- **`type`**: ENUM on both tables with exact same options (6 enum options)
- **`num`**: Unsigned Big Integer on both tables

---

Using `EXPLAIN`:
Both tables are using keys but the Extra column shows this for table 2: "Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort"

Removing the WHERE condition or LIMIT OFFSET has no effect, but I just noticed, removing the `ORDER BY` while keeping the LIMIT causes the query to run in less than 1ms

Not sure what is wrong here or what I should do, so any help is appreciated...

### Edit

```
/* Table 1 Keys */

KEY `posts_user_id_foreign` (`user_id`),
KEY `posts_composite_ind` (`post_followable_type`,`post_followable_id`,`id`) USING BTREE,
CONSTRAINT `posts_user_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=456501 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;


/* Table 2 Keys */

PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
UNIQUE KEY `unique_user_follows` (`user_id`,`followable_type`,`followable_id`),
CONSTRAINT `follows_user_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1525 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

/* Query */
SELECT
`posts`.*, `follows`.`user_id` AS `current_user`
FROM
`posts`
INNER JOIN `follows` 
    ON `follows`.`followable_type` = `post_followable_type`
    AND `follows`.`followable_id` = `post_followable_id`
WHERE
    `follows`.`user_id` = 1
ORDER BY
    `posts`.`id` DESC
LIMIT 11 OFFSET 0


/* Explain */

| id | select_type | table   | partitions | type | possible_keys       | key                 | key_len | ref                                                 | rows | filtered | Extra                                        |
|----|-------------|---------|------------|------|---------------------|---------------------|---------|-----------------------------------------------------|------|----------|----------------------------------------------|
|  1 | SIMPLE      | follows |            | ref  | unique_user_follows | unique_user_follows | 8       | const                                               |  511 |   100.00 | Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | posts   |            | ref  | posts_composite_ind | posts_composite_ind | 9       | db.follows.followable_type,db.follows.followable_id |  453 |   100.00 |                                              |

/* End */
```

Comment: Create index by `(type, num, id)` in table1 and by `(another_int, type, num)` in table2.

Comment: @Akina Both indexes are exactly like that, on table 2 `(another_int, type, num)` is actually a UNIQUE composite key, on table 1 there is a normal composite index set on `(type, num)` and `id` is primary separately.

Comment: Provide DDL for both tables and EXPLAIN for your query.

Comment: @Akina Just edited with everything you asked

Comment: Mmm... try to add STRAIGHT_JOIN for to fix tables scanning order posts->follows.

Comment: @Akina Wow... Thank you very much, just changing `INNER JOIN` with `STRAIGHT_JOIN` caused the original query to run in 1ms!!! Thank you again for sharing that keyword with me, I was not familiar with it. Sadly my framework does not support STRAIGHT_JOIN, but now that I know what the problem is, I'll do some research on how to fix it.

Comment: If you cannot use STRAIGHT_JOIN then you may try to use LEFT JOIN instead of INNER (it fixes table scanning order too), your WHERE will impilcitly convert your join type to INNER, so the output won't alter.

Comment: @Akina That worked too! I don't know how to thank you for teaching me these tricks. I wish you the best in life <3

Comment: @Akina - Really interesting info. Could you enter this as an answer so it will be easier for others to find this? I must admit that I never heard of STRAIGHT_JOIN before.

Comment: @MrApnea Indeed very useful info, I posted the solution below for future reference, but will wait for Akina's answer to set that one as accepted.

Comment: DO NOT USE that `STRAIGHT_JOIN`.  It woked nicely _for the current values_.  It is likely to work terribly slow for some other values!

Comment: @Akina - `LEFT JOIN` is turned into `INNER JOIN` when the Optimizer can see that they are equivalent.  Do `EXPLAIN SELECT ... ; SHOW WARNINGS`; to see "proof".  Meanwhile, `LEFT`, by itself, does not force table order.

Comment: @RickJames But as you saw, I already have all the necessary indexes. I will apply the suggestions in your answer right now, to see if that helps. specially getting rid of the id on table2. Thank you.

Comment: @RickJames The goal of LEFT JOIN usage is to fix the tables scanning order when STRAIGHT_JOIN is not applicable by any reason (for example, some framework does not support it) only. Yes, server understands that the joining type is INNER by fact - but its initiative in tables order selection is inhibited. *DO NOT USE that STRAIGHT_JOIN. It woked nicely for the current values.* Of course, this is rare hint which must be used individually, for particular query only, and cannot be recommended in general. Moreover, one must remember that data statistic change may make this hint harmful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

table2 needs `INDEX(another_int, num, type)`; `another_int` must be first.  But I guess you have that.

Get rid of `follows.id` and promote the `UNIQUE` key to be `PRIMARY KEY`.

table1 needs `INDEX(num, type)`; the columns can be in either order.  OK, I see that you have such an index.  No changed needed.

Comment: I did what you suggested, got rid of the `id` on table2 and made the composite unique key (`UNIQUE(another_int, num, type)`) primary, set on table1 `INDEX(num, type)` but issue still persists and it takes ~`1350ms`. I will work on this some more.

Comment: @J.Doe - Let's dig deeper.  `EXPLAIN FORMAT=JSON SELECT ...` sometime gives more insight.  And using the "Handler counts" may provide clues of table scans versus index lookups:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#handler_counts

Comment: Is it possible that after I made those changes, MySQL needed some time to gather and save indexes, etc? because before I went to sleep, it was running terribly, but now I tested again and my original query is running in `1ms` for all `another_int` values (without STRAIGHT_JOIN)... basically, I just changed my table1 index from `INDEX(type, num, id)` to `INDEX(type, num)` and removed primary key on my table2, set the existing `UNIQUE(another_int, num, type)` as primary instead. I hope these results will stay the same. Thank you very much though, the issue appears to be completely fixed!

Comment: Also thank you very much for teaching me about `EXPLAIN FORMAT=JSON` I just tested it, it returns much more usable data than normal EXPLAIN!

Comment: @J.Doe - In InnoDB, a secondary index implicitly has the Primary key's column(s) silently tacked onto the end of it.  When `id` was the PK, these were identical:  `INDEX(type, num, id)` and `INDEX(type, num)`.  Now `INDEX(type, num)` and `INDEX(type, num, another_int)` are identical.  So, yes, your changes are 'correct'.

Answer (score 0):

In case any one else has this issue:

Thanks to **@Akina**'s comments above, I learned about `STRAIGHT_JOIN`,

Sadly my framework didn't support `STRAIGHT_JOIN`, but I found out that you can also add this to the select query.

So here is the final solution, which runs in about `1ms` - `25ms`:

```
SELECT
    STRAIGHT_JOIN `table1`.*
FROM
    `table1`
    INNER JOIN `table2`
        ON  `table2.type` = `table1.type`
        AND `table2.num`  = `table1.num`
WHERE
    `table2.another_int` = 1
ORDER BY
    `table1`.`id` DESC
LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0
```

### EDIT

After trying the selected answer above, I ended up using it instead, as it fixed the issue without STRAIGHT_JOIN syntax.

Here is what changed:

```
/* previous indexes */
Table1: INDEX(type, num, id)
Table2: PRIMARY(id), UNIQUE(another_int, type, num)

/* new indexes */
Table1: INDEX(type, num)
Table2: PRIMARY(another_int, type, num)
```

Comment: Yet another reason why frameworks are more trouble than worth.

Comment: Before you celebrate too much, try some other values for `another_int`.  You may be disappointed.

Comment: @RickJames I think you are right that I shouldn't celebrate too much, I'm just happy I learned something new. I also tried every possible `another_int`, minimum time is `1ms` and the maximum for higher numbers is ~`25ms` which is very good IMHO. I'll do some more research in this area, maybe I will understand how MySQL plans these things and how I can optimize my query. Thank you very much.

Comment: I applaud your experimentation; it is a good way to learn.  And 25ms is great; I am actually surprised that you got that much speed as a worst-case.  Your query is a tricky one [in my opinion] -- it can be very fast or very slow, and there is no simple way, even with the help of the Optimizer, to make it always "good".  If there is a "user" waiting for the answer, it tends to be good to "optimize for the worst case".  If the system is being overloaded with such queries, one needs to "optimize for the average case".